# Selective Automatic Schema Generation settings per entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, properties, entity, database-schema

Is it possible to selectively choose to which entities or datasources the schema generation settings of Hibernate apply?

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none

I´d like to use existing tables of a database that I don´t want to modify, but also create some new ones automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ->hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update instead of none.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a nice article that describes how to do that by defining multiple configuration classes pointing to different entity packages. It seems the only way is to do that programmatically.

For the existing database table where I don´t want to create or update any tables I´d have the following config with **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** set to **none**

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:existing-database.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.model.existing")
@Configuration
public class ExistingDatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.project.model.existing");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("user.jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

And for those entities that where tables should be created I´d have a separate config with **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** set to **create-or-update**:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:not-existing-database.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.model.notexisting")
@Configuration
public class NotExistingDatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.project.model.notexisting");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-or-update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("user.jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could do that in the persistence.xml file, defining two persistence units.